# How can we run an xml file using TCL Script?

Tags: xml, unix, tcl

I have an `XML` file located on a Unix server. How can I run that `XML` file using a `Tcl` script?

Comment: What does 'run an xml file' mean?  XML files are data storage devices with name value pairs.

Comment: are you trying to parse an XML doc using TCL?

Comment: Streamlined by removing redundant statements. Formatted technical terminology.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a simple way to parse (if that's what you mean by run) XML, consider tdom package.

Reference: http://wiki.tcl.tk/8984

Here's a file foo.xml with the following content:

```
<my_root>
    <my_child1>
        <my_subchild1 foo="bar">bat</my_subchild1>
    </my_child1>
</my_root>
```

---

Read the xml data into a variable (not the best way if the XML content is large):

```
%   
% set fd [open foo.xml]
file3
% set xml [read $fd]
<my_root>
    <my_child1>
        <my_subchild1 foo="bar">bat</my_subchild1>
    </my_child1>
</my_root>

% close $fd
%
```

---

Now parse it:

```
% package require tdom
0.8.3
% 
% set documentHandle [dom parse $xml]
domDoc0x2510320
% set root [$documentHandle documentElement]
domNode0x2546d90
% $root asXML
<my_root>
    <my_child1>
        <my_subchild1 foo="bar">bat</my_subchild1>
    </my_child1>
</my_root>

% set child1 [$root firstChild]
domNode0x16dcec0
% $child1 asXML
<my_child1>
    <my_subchild1 foo="bar">bat</my_subchild1>
</my_child1>

% set tmp [$root selectNodes //my_subchild1]
domNode0x16dd630
% $tmp asXML
<my_subchild1 foo="bar">bat</my_subchild1>

% $tmp getAttribute foo
bar
% $tmp text
bat
%
```

---

Here's the list of supported command with a parsed xml node:

```
% $tmp
Usage nodeObj <method> <args>, where method can be:
    nodeType                     
    nodeName                     
    nodeValue ?newValue?         
    hasChildNodes                
    childNodes                   
    childNodesLive               
    parentNode                   
    firstChild ?nodeObjVar?      
    lastChild ?nodeObjVar?       
    nextSibling ?nodeObjVar?     
    previousSibling ?nodeObjVar? 
    hasAttribute attrName        
    getAttribute attrName ?defaultValue? 
    setAttribute attrName value ?attrName value ...? 
    removeAttribute attrName     
    hasAttributeNS uri localName 
    getAttributeNS uri localName ?defaultValue? 
    setAttributeNS uri attrName value ?attrName value ...? 
    removeAttributeNS uri attrName 
    attributes ?attrNamePattern?   
    appendChild new              
    insertBefore new ref         
    replaceChild new old         
    removeChild child            
    cloneNode ?-deep?            
    ownerDocument                
    getElementsByTagName name    
    getElementsByTagNameNS uri localname 
    getElementById id            
    find attrName attrValue ?nodeObjVar?   
    child      number|all ?type? ?attrName attrValue? 
    descendant number|all ?type? ?attrName attrValue? 
    ancestor   number|all ?type? ?attrName attrValue? 
    fsibling   number|all ?type? ?attrName attrValue? 
    psibling   number|all ?type? ?attrName attrValue? 
    root ?nodeObjVar?            
    target                       
    data                         
    text                         
    prefix                       
    namespaceURI                 
    getBaseURI                   
    baseURI ?URI?                
    localName                    
    delete                       
    getLine                      
    getColumn                    
    @<attrName> ?defaultValue?   
    asList                       
    asXML ?-indent <none,0..8>? ?-channel <channel>? ?-escapeNonASCII? ?-escapeAllQuot? ?-doctypeDeclaration <boolean>?
    asHTML ?-channel <channelId>? ?-escapeNonASCII? ?-htmlEntities?
    asText                       
    appendFromList nestedList    
    appendFromScript script      
    insertBeforeFromScript script ref 
    appendXML xmlString          
    selectNodes ?-namespaces prefixUriList? ?-cache <boolean>? xpathQuery ?typeVar? 
    toXPath                      
    disableOutputEscaping ?boolean? 
    precedes node                
    normalize ?-forXPath?        
    xslt ?-parameters parameterList? <xsltDocNode>
    readlock                     
    writelock                    

%
```